# How to convert list object type in 3rd dimension of 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

A bit of background:
Initially, I had the error `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).` after attempting to convert `my_list` into a tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor()` .

I have a 3D numpy array `my_list` with the following properties:

[image]

As you can see in run [321] the 3rd dimension is a type `list`. I would like to convert it into a `numpy.ndarray` type too. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `my_list` is a 3d object dtype array containing lists.  `np.array(my_list.tolist())` might return a 4d float array.

Comment: @AloneTogether oh that makes sense. I'll edit the post and include reproducible code. Thanks for the feedback! I appreciate it.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried your code and it worked! I think your comment deserves to be the best answer for this question. I will update the question tomorrow to include reproducible code along with your suggested code. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

- my_list only contains actual numbers, not other objects like a string
- All entries of the same hierarchy have the same length, i.e. len(my_list[0]) == len(my_list[1])

To convert into an numpy array (in all dimensions at once):

```
my_array = np.array(my_list)
```

To replace a certain element with an array:

```
my_array[0][0] = np.array(my_array[0][0])
```

Comment: `my_list` contains only actual numbers and they have all the same hierarchy and length. I already tried `np.array()`. In fact, I already applied it. `my_list = np.array(original_list)` . Thus, the `type(my_list)` is a `numpy_ndarray`. The second code block is not practical as I have 1000 elements in `my_list` and a for loop takes a long time for deployment purposes.  I hope that made things clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `my_list` is a 3d `object dtype` array containing lists. `np.array(my_list.tolist())` might return a 4d float array

`tolist` is a relatively fast way of creating a list (nested if necessary) of the root objects.  `np.array` can than convert it to a numeric dtype array - assuming the root lists all have the same shape.

`np.stack` is also useful, but it only works if the object dtype array is 1d.